# Cordova record audio without sound recorder

Tags: cordova, audio-recording

I'm using this plugin `cordova-plugin-media-capture` to record audio, when i tap start recording, the plugin launch `sound recorder` app to record the audio, but i don't want that, i want something like `WhatsApp`, to record the audio without leaving my app (meaning without using another app `sound recorder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cordova-plugin-media` instad, it has audio recording capabilities with `startRecord`

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#mediastartrecord

```
var my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
my_media.startRecord();
```

Comment: ok thanks, where can i find the recorded file? does they save it somewhere, and if i close the app, does recorded files got removed or they keep it?

Comment: In the src you can provide the full path

Comment: yes i know, my question was about the location of the recorded file, for example `src = "audio.mp3"`, where is the location of  `audio.mp3` ? 2- is it a temporary file, meaning does that file got deleted after closing the app or not?

Comment: If you provide the full path you can choose if it’s a persistent storage or not. If you just provide the name, it will use a temporary location for iOS

Comment: Ok, if i provide the name, does it use a temporary location for Android too or just IOS?

Comment: The docs don't say anything about it, so I suppose it's not temporary, but you can just test it and check it by yourself.